# osm2pgsql --append super slow (node 2k/s vs 1500k/s for --create)

Tags: postgresql, osm2pgsql

I'm working with multiple pbf files (one per administrative region). I thought I would import them one by one in postgis, with:

```
osm2pgsql --proj 4326 --hstore-all --database gis first.pbf --style custom.style --slim --flat-nodes osm2pgsql.flatnodes --create
for file in other_pbfs; do 
    osm2pgsql --proj 4326 --hstore-all --database gis $file.pbf --style custom.style --slim --flat-nodes osm2pgsql.flatnodes --append
done
```

However, the first import (`--create`) is going quite fast:

> Processing: Node(262182k 1691.5k/s) Way(38130k 125.43k/s) Relation(0 0.00/s)

While the second one (`--append`) is going… super slow:

> Processing: Node(13k 2.5k/s) Way(0 0.00/s) Relation(0 0.00/s)

If I merge these two PBFs before import (`osmium merge *.pbf -o output.pbf`), it goes fast again but I'd like to remove that unnecessary step if possible?

I tried with different formats (`.pbf`, `.osm`, …) but there is no changes in speed results.

Comment: did it even finish with `--append`?? ...that mode is solely for updating *existing* data with the proper *diff* files (`.osc`) provided by e.g. *Geofabrik*. it is simply not meant to add data...merging your data prior to the import is the best way to go here I'm afraid...

Comment: no it indeed never finished… But if it's only for merging diff files... I guess that's the reason :).