# osm2pgsql stops after importing several extracts

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I want to import several city extracts from the bbike website into my postgis database. I use windows on a desktop pc with 16GB RAM and a quadcore processor. The first couple of extracts imported fairly well. I used this command:

```
osm2pgsql --append -s --database <database>--username <username> <path to pbf>
```

After around 10 extracts the import looks like it stopped (Speed 0.0k) without any error message or it is extremely slow. When I add the cache flag and set it to 12000 it has now effect.

Looking at pgadmin there still seems to be activity on the db. This is what my pgAdmin panel looks like:

[image]

Did anyone experience the same and got a solution?
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: From my 1TB harddrive roughly half of it is full. Should have 400GB + still free.

Comment: Is Postgres working "hard" in the background? It may be rebuilding the indexes, which will take longer and longer as the DB size increase. You may want to play with PG configuration to give it more resources (like maintenance_work_mem) during the load

Comment: I added a screenshot from my pgAdmin panel. It seems like the amount of processed nodes is rising very slowly while speed is indicated at 0.0k. But with this speed even the import of one single city extract would take forever.
How can I figure out whether the indexes are the reason for that?

Comment: It seems like that --append is the problem. It is not meant to do what I think it does. I found the following question and the comments might explain my problem:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294037/osm2pgsql-append-super-slow-node-2k-s-vs-1500k-s-for-create